# overwrite destructor for antlr3 C++ target from grammar

Tags: c++, parsing, destructor, antlr3

I'm using the C++ target for antlr3. I have completed my grammar, parser, and I've been supporting it successfully for a few months. I've found recently I need to introduce some Parser member variables (which I found out how to add), but now I need to know how to overwrite the destructor for the C++ target. I could do this by hand, but I would like it to be placed correctly each time I generate the parser from the grammar. I also understand I could rely on a class destructor, but I'd rather not add another class just to use the destructor when the Parser's own destructor is perfectly valid.

Comment: Do you have example of your grammar? I've created some examples in mine branch. Maybe you will find this usefull: https://github.com/ibre5041/antlr3/tree/master/runtime/Cpp/tests

Comment: Also the C++ is based on "Curiously recurring template pattern". You can also "inject" ancestor instead of subclassing. You can define the trait BaseParserType, and the generated Parser grammar will inherit your class.

Comment: I see that you have a lot of grammars here, but do any contain any custom destructors at the parser level? What I'm trying to do is overwrite User::XParser::~XParser() so that it cleans up when the parser goes out of scope.

Comment: Ok then you cal also check: https://github.com/ibre5041/tora/blob/master/extlibs/parsing.cpp/UserTraits.hpp . There is BaseLexerType defined. There is no destructor defined (yet). But you can define it. You can also put your own member variables into your Base class. The generate lexer/parser will inherit this class then. AFAIK this approach is called "Base class decorator design pattern". Instead subclassing(and using virtual methods) you "inject" different baseclass(ancestor) to your class.